# If a cell is empty, then it is equal to the cell next to it; if the cell is not empty, then do nothing

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

For example, there is some value in cell B1 of my worksheet, and cell C1 is empty (there's no value in it). I would like excel to populate cell C1 with the value in cell B1 if C1 is empty. If cell C1 is not empty (i.e. there's some value in it), then I would like Excel to do nothing. The same goes for D1 and E1... if they are empty, I would like Excel to populate them with the value in cel B1; if not, then do nothing. Can you please show me how to do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of VBA

1. Firstly you need to use `Worksheet_Change` or `Workbook_Sheetchange` to keep track of changes.
2. Get the value of the Cell C1 and B1
3. If C1.value = NULL, then C1.value = B1.value

You need to write the code by yourself.